# Why is Java used for low latency but C# isn't really?

Tags: c#, java, .net

Java and C# are pretty much identical, both have garbage collectors, similar memory models (well, at least compared with C++), similar memory allocation (I think) but Java is used fairly often in low latency applications (not as much as C++) whereas C# isn't really..

Are there any technical reasons why C#, even though it is very similar to Java, is not used in these environments? Are there differences in the memory model etc? Is it because Java has different JVMs/Garbage collectors? Better tuning parameters?

EDIT: After one of the comments below I believe the answer to this (closed) question is that C# limits the system to being Windows-based. Linux allows tuning the server to context-switch far less and therefore provider greater low latency opportunities, rather than this being about the C# language-specifics itself.

Comment: What low level applications are you refering to?

Comment: Can you back these assertions up with facts, or do we have to take your word for it?

Comment: @Daan, high frequency trading for example.

Comment: @Jon, go and look at as many High Frequency job adverts as you can. You will only see C++ and Java for the low latency roles. I know of one hedge fund who use C# and that is only for their front end. Their back end is all C++. I know a fair few people who work in HF and they all agree C# is hardly used for the low latency parts.

Comment: @Jon, C# is NOT used as much as Java for low latency. That is a fact and unless you can find a lot of C# job adverts for it- what I have said is correct. With that in mind I am asking is this for technical reasons- which is a perfectly valid question!

Comment: I ment low latency of course btw.

Comment: @user997112: So it sounds like there *is* a reason: all of those outfits already have applications, written before C# existed, and they are not interested in rewriting them for no benefit. Because from a purely technical standpoint, I 'm sure you could write them just as well in Perl and Javascript.

Comment: @Jon, even greenfield High Frequency platforms are being written in Java or C++, not C#. I know about 20 companies who work in this area, approximately 65% use C++ and the other 35% use Java. I do not think it is for legacy reasons...

Comment: You should look at other reasons bar low latency though. Java being much older(and thus already have an establised code base in these companies), and do not require windows (other C# implementations are likely not even considered based on maturity) are likely the main reasons. I do think the legacy reasons are really a main reason. (remember, legacy might not just be about the code, but the people too).

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1641533/284240 or this link http://vanillajava.blogspot.de/2011/07/c-or-java-which-is-faster-for-high.html

Comment: @Nos- I think that is probably the reason. Most companies in this area prefer Unix over Windows any day!

Comment: The reason Java is used so heavily is that pretty much the standard interoperability library is a Java library (called QUICKFIX/J), and this library has the capability to call into C++, C or assembly code for low-latency purposes.  So, Java has become the standard platform for most orginizations because of this.  If such a library were written for .NET, then .NET could do the same things.. but so far nobody has written such a library that i'm aware of. (NOTE: there is a quickfix managed wrapper that wraps the c++ dll, but it's not a native library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: How can you possibly expect a valid answer to a false premise?

Relevant links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232761.aspx
- http://www.elitetrader.com/vb/printthread.php?threadid=204368

Comment: But it's not a false premise....

Comment: @user997112 - there are few, if any, technical reasons to favor C#/.Net over Java or vice versa.  Take a look at the above links.  If a particular industry favors one or the other, I'll wager it's probably other issues like a) existing investment in Java (which, personally, I prefer), b) not wanting to rely on Microsoft platforms (for example, even if I might be willing to use C#, I'm required to run on a zOs workstation)

Comment: @user997112 In China, Java is far more popular than .NET, there are reasons behind it, to me, I think the core reason is $$$. And I think C#.NET with no problems developing general low latency application, example like financial market application.

Comment: Much has happened since this thread was started in 2012.  Including Java becoming much more "closed source" since Oracle's acquisition in 2010, and .Net becoming much more "open source" with the introduction of [.Net Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform).  And don't forget [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), which is still Alive and Well ...